# If premium delivery option is free, should it be placed above cheaper options?

Tags: checkout, pricing

On an e-commerce website, let's say you have 3 delivery options...

1. Standard delivery for £3
2. Next day delivery for £5
3. Next day morning delivery for £8

By default, the first option is selected (Standard delivery).

Now lets say the customer uses a promo code to qualify for the premium Next Day delivery, which of the following behaviours would you expect...

**Option 1**

The order remains the same but 'Next day delivery' is pre-selected.

**Option 2**

'Next day delivery' is pre-selected AND is moved to the top of the list, so the new order would look like this...

1. Next day delivery for FREE
2. Standard delivery for £3
3. Next day morning delivery for £8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of each payment plan goes from lowest to highest price and advantage. Changing the order of the promotion obtained, whatever it may be, eliminates the sequence from lowest to highest, both in price and benefits, so the user:

- They will not know the real advantage of their promotion
- They will lose the comparative visual reference of the promotion
  obtained
- They will not know how much money they are saving

I would keep the same order and highlight the promotion:

1. Standard delivery for £3
2. Next-day delivery <s>for £5</s> **FREE**
3. Next day morning delivery for £8

Comment: Thank you, completely agree.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Danielillo, but for a different reason:

### Don't mode UI elements around when you don't have to - it makes your interfaces look fiddly

Presumably, your users come back more than once; having all the elements at the same place introduces familiarity and security. **Go with Option 1**.